# How to use equals() to replace "String1==String2" in Android Studio? Would any of the esteemed members explain it with examples?

Tags: string, android-studio, equals

Hi please explain how to use equals () in Android Studio when using strings to replace String1==String2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

To compare two strings, use [String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

```
string1.equals(string2);
```

However, keep in mind you'll need to do a `null` check on `string1` first else you may end up with a `NullPointerException`. A `null`-safe version could look like:

```
boolean match = (string1 == null ? string2 == null : string1.equals(string2));
```

One more Android-specific alternative is:

```
TextUtils.equals(string1, string2);
```